# stopPropagation() preventing childs onClick functions

Tags: jquery, onclick, stoppropagation

I've searched everywhere and I couldn't find an answer to this question.

I've built a menu with couple of divs inside divs:

```
<nav id="menu">
   <span>Open Menu</span>

   <div class="dropdownContain">
       <div class="dropOut">
          ...
          ...
          <div id="logout_wrap">
             <a id="logout">
```

And a script using JQuery so that menu appears (toggle) when "#menu" is clicked and disappear when body is clicked. for this functionality I had to use stopPropagation() method to stop #dropDownContain from running "body" 's hide() function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menu').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.dropdownContain').toggle();
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('.dropdownContain').hide();
    });

    $('.dropdownContain').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

also I have made a click event for "#logout" which is inside "#dropdownContain" (which is the main body of menu) to run someThing() function.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#logout', function () {
    alert("THIS DOES NOT WORK");
});
```

The problem is that "#logout" 's assigned function will not fire because of the stopPropagation() method that is called in it's parent (or so I think).

here's the link to html + js for this code, just so you could see it in use:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7G7aP/1/)

so is there a solution to fix this while keeping the menu popup working as explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using stopPropagation and manually check if the click was inside `#menu` or not :

```
$('#menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdownContain').toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (! $(e.target).is('#menu') || $(e.target).closest('#menu').length )
        $('.dropdownContain').hide();
});
```

Comment: this seems like a solution but I can't make this work. could you please implement this in the JSFiddle link I provided in the question.

Comment: Thanks. It couldn't toggle but with a few modifications it worked just like I wanted to. Here's the link to the final working one just in case: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7G7aP/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a reason for using event delegation, you can just bind the click directly to the logout link.

```
jQuery('#logout').on('click', function () {
    alert("this works");
});
```

The delegated version you were using only fires when the event bubbles all the way back to the `body` element (which it won't, since you're stopping the propagation.)

Comment: This indeed works. but the problem is I'm not the one generating "#logout"'s onclick code. my php framework (yii) is. so I can't change that. isn't there a way without changing "#logout" onclick  code?