# How would I hide an element when one is clicked, and show the hidden element when the other element is clicked off of?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, stoppropagation

I have two classes:

```
.dropdown-toggle
```

and

```
.link_row ul
```

What I want to do is, when the user clicks on the .dropdown-toggle, I want the .link_row ul to be set to not be displayed.  When the user clicks off of the .dropdown-toggle, I want the .link_row ul to be displayed again.  How would this be done in javascript/jquery?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15531272/1104483

Comment: Thanks @VitaliyPetrychuk. I followed that thread and got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `toggle` method inside the click event.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.link_row ul').toggle();
});
```